# Only 8 devices can connect to my pi 4

Tags: wireless, connection, access-point

I conducted tests today with a Rpi4 4Gb RAM as a wireless access point and I wasn't able to connect more than 8 devices. But then I want to be able to connect at least 20 devices. Pls, help.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, 8 clients connected, no more.
RPI4 (4g ram), Buster updated.

In the end, @pelwell is right here [#3010 (comment)](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3010#issuecomment-748484728), so if you're just looking to increase the number of connected clients, then take a look at this table [iiab/iiab#823](https://github.com/iiab/iiab/issues/823).

Take 7.45.18.0 (follow the link) and replace /var/lib/firmware/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin (of course, make a backup first). Reboot.

I've done it 2 days ago and until now I see no issues, stability seems okay, 20 clients connected.
Check this Github comment https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3010#issuecomment-788323744